# xUnit tests won't run due to exception during test discovery

Tags: c#, visual-studio, testing, xunit

I created a new xUnit test project in Visual Studio and add a couple simple tests.    But when I try to run any of them, they don't run because, according to the Test output, the discovery is aborted.  I see the following stack trace there

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestPlatformException: Could not find testhost
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Hosting.DotnetTestHostManager.GetTestHostProcessStartInfo(IEnumerable`1 sources, IDictionary`2 environmentVariables, TestRunnerConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyOperationManager.SetupChannel(IEnumerable`1 sources, String runSettings)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyDiscoveryManager.InitializeDiscovery(DiscoveryCriteria discoveryCriteria, ITestDiscoveryEventsHandler2 eventHandler, Boolean skipDefaultAdapters)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestPlatformException: Could not find testhost
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Hosting.DotnetTestHostManager.GetTestHostProcessStartInfo(IEnumerable`1 sources, IDictionary`2 environmentVariables, TestRunnerConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyOperationManager.SetupChannel(IEnumerable`1 sources, String runSettings)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyDiscoveryManager.InitializeDiscovery(DiscoveryCriteria discoveryCriteria, ITestDiscoveryEventsHandler2 eventHandler, Boolean skipDefaultAdapters)
System.InvalidOperationException: The provided manager was not found in any slot.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ParallelOperationManager`3.ClearCompletedSlot(TManager completedManager)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ParallelOperationManager`3.RunNextWork(TManager completedManager)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.Parallel.ParallelProxyDiscoveryManager.HandlePartialDiscoveryComplete(IProxyDiscoveryManager proxyDiscoveryManager, Int64 totalTests, IEnumerable`1 lastChunk, Boolean isAborted)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.Parallel.ParallelDiscoveryEventsHandler.HandleDiscoveryComplete(DiscoveryCompleteEventArgs discoveryCompleteEventArgs, IEnumerable`1 lastChunk)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyDiscoveryManager.InitializeDiscovery(DiscoveryCriteria discoveryCriteria, ITestDiscoveryEventsHandler2 eventHandler, Boolean skipDefaultAdapters)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyDiscoveryManager.DiscoverTests(DiscoveryCriteria discoveryCriteria, ITestDiscoveryEventsHandler2 eventHandler)
```

I'm not sure how to proceed.

These tests are meant to test a number of assemblies all of which have  a `TargetFramework` property set to `net7.0-windows` in the .csproj file.    So I had to change the `TargetFramework` of test project as well.  Could that have anything to do with it?

Also I am running Visual Studio 2022 17.6.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question in case someone else hits the same problem.  This is embarrassing.

When I created my test project, I neglected to change the output folder setting so that its binary output would go to the same, shared folder that all my other assembly binaries go to.  So I guess it couldn't find many of the dependencies it needed at run time.  Once I corrected that, everything went away.

I literally spent hours on this.  So dumb.

Comment: You can mark your answer so that you can help more people

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT I will eventually, but StackOverflow forces me to wait two days to do so

Comment: Thank you for your support to the platform